# Nomear arquivo com dado de consulta sql

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá, preciso nomear cada arquivo criado pelo script com um dado de uma única coluna do meu banco de dado.
Segue o código:

```
for index, source in zip(list(range(0, len(self.sources))), self.sources):
  if self.jsonfile is not None and self.outdir is not None:
    path_file = '{}/{}_{}_{}'.format(self.outdir,datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'), index, code[index]+'.json')
```

Onde "code" é o dado da minha coluna do banco de dado, e index é o numero os arquivos e vai ficar pra ficar assim:

20170920145732_0_CODE1.json

20170920145732_1_CODE2.json

20170920145732_2_CODE3.json

Os números iniciais são data e hora e depois do primeiro underscore vem o index, e por ultimo vem o dado da coluna do banco de dados.

Minha consulta sql:

```
sql = 'SELECT code from data.est where name = code and id = 13'
```

Comment: Desconsiderando os erros de indentação e um `for` mal construído, qual o problema? Você disse o que pretende fazer, mas não explicou o que fez nem qual a dificuldade encontrada.

Comment: Os erros de identação estão apenas aqui no post, no script está correto. O que acontece é o seguinte, ele não renomeia os arquivos como desejado nem cria o arquivo. Como pode ver na imagem, o código está identado corretamente: https://imgur.com/YApOJAT

Comment: Consegue me disponibilizar como seria a árvore do .json que imagina de resultado?